# Несмотря на то(,) что устал

Tags: орфография

Нужна ли-с запятая?

`Я всегда делаю всё, несмотря на то(,) что устал.`

P. S. Просто дело в том, что я увидел такой вариант:

`Я всегда делаю всё, несмотря на то, что устал.`

Мне, однако, кажется, что 2-я запятая лишняя.

P. S. S. Меня уже задолбал этот союз несчастный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Я всегда делаю всЁ, // **несмотря на то что устал**.*

**Других вариантов нет.**

Это предложение интонационно можно разделить **только на две части**, но не на три. Если мы делим его запятыми на **три  части**, то это не соответствует **интонационному** принципу пунктуации. Но **грамматическому** принципу это тоже не соответствует.

**Пример**. *Он продолжает так делать, будто и **не видя то, что** происходит*. Знакомое предложение?  Да, но это другая грамматика: деепричастие + указательное слово + изъяснительное придаточное.

Может, поэтому ПАС не спешит "благословить" это правило расчленения союза. Вместо придаточного уступительного мы получаем неизвестный **гибрид**.

**О расчленении союза НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО, который всех "задолбал"** (лучше и **не вспоминать** о нем).

Справочная служба (Грамота.ру) берет на себя смелость устанавливать **особый порядок расчленения этого союза,** которого нет больше нигде (Розенталь, ПАС, грамматика).

**[Справочник](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_483)**

Здесь приводятся примеры преимущественно из литературы XIX века.

**[Теория](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3)**

**Некоторые закономерности**

**Анализ примеров из художественной литературы** позволяет разделить составные подчинительные союзы на четыре группы (в зависимости от особенностей пунктуационного оформления) и выявить **следующие закономерности:**

**1. Составные подчинительные союзы** ввиду того что; вместо того чтобы; в случае если / когда; в то время как; для того чтобы; до того как; мало того что; на случай если; несмотря на то что; оттого что; перед тем как; подобно тому как; по мере того как; после того как; потому что; прежде чем; при том что; с тем чтобы; с тех пор как **могут целиком входить в придаточную часть** (и не разделяться запятой), **но могут и расчленяться** – в зависимости от приведенных выше условий.

При этом следует отметить, что союзы ввиду того что, до того как, на случай если чаще расчленяются, союз прежде чем чаще не расчленяется, а перед союзом ***НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО ЧТО*** запятая **сохраняется и в случае его расчленения** (это обусловлено тем, что союз образован при участии **отглагольного** предлога).

Другими словами, именно для этого союза справочная служба устанавливает **особое правило.**

**Насколько это правомерно?**  Лингвисты пытаются оправдать свое решение, но меня подобные объяснения не устраивают. Вот когда это правило (**для одного союза!**) будет официально признано, тогда и надо **делить придаточное на две части.**

Comment: А почему он тогда увидел расчлененный? Плюсую ваш ответ

Comment: В простых предложениях видно, что предложение делится на две фонетические фразы.  Если же предложение распространенное, то добавляется произносительная пауза (ее-то и обозначают запятой "по правилу Грамоты).  Этот союз книжный, и он чаще используется именно в распространенных предложениях.

Comment: А фонетические фразы когда появляются? Когда ставится мегапауза?

Comment: Там скорее наоборот: любая конструкция состоит из фонетических фраз,  при этом каждая фраза обязана иметь одно полноценное фразовое ударение (повышение или понижение голоса). А паузы соответствуют ударениям: грамматическая пауза ("мегапауза") делается между фразами. Но если фраза распространенная, то ее приходится делить на произносительные отрезки (синтагмы) и делать между ними произносительные (короткие) паузы. Запятыми мы обозначаем грамматические паузы.

Comment: А как их обнаружить? Ыразы с помощью больших пауз, а синтагмы — небольших? Или не так?

Comment: Ищите фразы, а не паузы. Паузы вторичны и зависимы. Сделайте ударение на слове, и у вас уже получается пауза. Чем сильнее ударение, тем больше эта пауза.  А фразовое ударение (подчеркнутое изменение тона) характерно для фраз.

Comment: А сами фразы тогда как найти?

Comment: Максим, вот я набираю в Яндексе такой запрос:  Что такое фраза в фонетике?  Поисковик предлагает много материала, Можно выбрать то, что понятно вам. Точно так же можно проверить остальные термины, и тогда вы получите представление об очень многом.  Еще хорошо спросить: Какие бывают виды ударений? Что такое тоническое и фразовое ударение? К источникам  (нужно подобрать авторитетный) больше доверия.  Здесь же мы можем на практике применить этту теорию. Ведь интересно!

Answer (score 2):

Ставится запятая или нет — зависит от интонационного выделения первой части союза (*несмотря на тО*) автором.

***Я всегда делаю всë, несмотря на тО, что устал.*** Здесь автор выделяет интонацией первую часть союза, поэтому запятая стоит.

***Я всегда делаю всë, несмотря на то что устал.*** Здесь автор не выделяет интонацией первую часть союза.

Поэтому запятая зависит только от вашей интонации. Во встретившемся вам предложении его автор, значит, выделил первую часть интонацией.

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку не правило Розенталя или ПАС, где позволяется делить СПП на три части (1-й вариант).

Comment: Я Розенталя не читал. Про этот союз есть на «Грамоте» и, в принципе, на этом же форуме

Comment: "Грамота" имеет статус официального источника? Я думаю, что нет. Это грамматика к тому же.  Какие придаточные позволительно делить на части?  Я про такое не слышала.